# Is there a way to place a widget into more than one of the tabs of a QTabWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, instance, qtabwidget

The motivating scenario:  I'm working on a Qt/QWidgets C++ app whose GUI is largely arranged into tabs, via a hierarchy of `QTabWidget`s.  Many of these tabs are various agglomerations of the same content, (e.g. there's a tab with widget `A` and `B`, a tab with widget `B` and `C`, and so on).

I have one particular widget class `W` which is a fairly heavyweight GUI object and it appears in many (but not all) of the tabs.  Currently I handle that by simply creating a separate object of the `W` class for each tab I want it to appear in, and that basically works, but it's not 100% satisfactory for a couple of reasons:

1. Since the widget is heavy, creating a number of instances of it slows down the GUI's creation on startup, and uses more system resources than I would like.
2. Every time the user changes the layout/state of the widget in one tab, I have to manually echo that change to all of its "clones" in the other tabs; otherwise the user will notice the different states of the different W widgets as he moves back and forth from one tab to another.  This is doable, but it's a maintenance and testing headache.

So what I'd like to do is create just a single instance of `W` and have it magically appear in its expected location within whichever tab is currently visible.  Since only one tab with `W` should ever be visible at one time, it seems like a single `W` instance ought to be enough to accomplish that.

I thought about making a lightweight proxy/container-widget of some sort, and overriding its `showEvent()` method to `setParent()` the real `W` object to be its child as necessary; I think that might work, or it might turn out to be full of gotchas, so I thought I'd ask first if anyone else knows of a more elegant or better-supported way to accomplish the same result.

Comment: Since Qt organizes its data in parent-child relationships, I doubt this works. Normally you solve this by having one model (simple QObject) attached to several views (set of widgets). If you worry about startup, you can delay initializing tabs until they are first opened, or initialize them in a singleshot timer after opening the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [a little help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75098903/131930) I was able to make this technique work, as shown in the example code below.  Note that the green label "Shared Widget!" is only created once, but it appears in all 5 tabs (along with various normal QLabels):

[image: demo screenshot]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMap>
#include <QSet>
#include <QStackedLayout>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QWidget>

/** This is a special container-class that holds a single target widget so that the target widget can be placed
  * into more than one QTabWidget at a time.  This widget will handle moving the target widget around from proxy
  * to proxy as tabs are shown, so that instead of having to create N identical widgets, we can just create one
  * target-widget and have it jump from tab to tab as necessary.
  */
class TabProxyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
   /** Constructor
     * @param optTargetWidget if non-NULL, this will be passed to SetTargetWidget().  Defaults to NULL.
     */
   TabProxyWidget(QWidget * optTargetWidget = NULL)
      : _layout(new QStackedLayout(this))
      , _targetWidget(NULL)
   {
      SetTargetWidget(optTargetWidget);
   }

   virtual ~TabProxyWidget() {SetTargetWidget(NULL);}

   /** Set the widget that we want to be a proxy for
     * @param optTargetWidget the widget we will proxy for, or NULL to disassociate us from any target widget
     * @note the same pointer for (optTargetWidget) can (and should!) be passed to multiple TabProxyWidget objects
     */
   void SetTargetWidget(QWidget * optTargetWidget);

   virtual void showEvent(QShowEvent *);
   virtual bool eventFilter(QObject * o, QEvent * e);

private:
   void AdoptTargetWidget();
   void UpdateSizeConstraints();

   QStackedLayout * _layout;
   QWidget * _targetWidget;
};

static QMap<QWidget *, QSet<TabProxyWidget *> > _targetWidgetToProxies;

void TabProxyWidget :: SetTargetWidget(QWidget * targetWidget)
{
   if (targetWidget != _targetWidget)
   {
      if (_targetWidget)
      {
         _targetWidget->removeEventFilter(this);

         QSet<TabProxyWidget *> * proxiesForTargetWidget = _targetWidgetToProxies.contains(_targetWidget) ? &_targetWidgetToProxies[_targetWidget] : NULL;
         if ((proxiesForTargetWidget == NULL)||(proxiesForTargetWidget->isEmpty()))
         {
            printf("TabProxyWidget::SetTargetWidget(NULL):  can't proxies-table for target widget %p is %s!\n", targetWidget, proxiesForTargetWidget?"empty":"missing");
            exit(10);
         }

         (void) proxiesForTargetWidget->remove(this);
         if (proxiesForTargetWidget->isEmpty())
         {
            (void) _targetWidgetToProxies.remove(_targetWidget);
            delete _targetWidget;
         }
         else if (dynamic_cast<TabProxyWidget *>(_targetWidget->parentWidget()) == this)
         {
            proxiesForTargetWidget->values()[0]->AdoptTargetWidget();  // hand him off to another proxy to for safekeeping
         }
      }

      _targetWidget = targetWidget;

      if (_targetWidget)
      {
         if (_targetWidgetToProxies.contains(_targetWidget) == false) _targetWidgetToProxies[_targetWidget] = QSet<TabProxyWidget *>();
         _targetWidgetToProxies[_targetWidget].insert(this);

         if ((isHidden() == false)||(_targetWidget->parentWidget() == NULL)||(dynamic_cast<TabProxyWidget *>(_targetWidget->parentWidget()) == NULL)) AdoptTargetWidget();

         UpdateSizeConstraints();
         _targetWidget->installEventFilter(this);
      }
   }
}

bool TabProxyWidget :: eventFilter(QObject * o, QEvent * e)
{
   if ((o == _targetWidget)&&(e->type() == QEvent::Resize)) UpdateSizeConstraints();
   return QWidget::eventFilter(o, e);
}

void TabProxyWidget :: UpdateSizeConstraints()
{
   if (_targetWidget)
   {
      setMinimumSize(_targetWidget->minimumSize());
      setMaximumSize(_targetWidget->maximumSize());
      setSizePolicy (_primaryWidget->sizePolicy());
   }
   else
   {
      setMinimumSize(QSize(0,0));
      setMaximumSize(QSize(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX, QWIDGETSIZE_MAX));
      setSizePolicy (QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored));
   }
}

void TabProxyWidget :: showEvent(QShowEvent * e)
{
   AdoptTargetWidget();
   QWidget::showEvent(e);
   if (_targetWidget) _targetWidget->show();
}

void TabProxyWidget :: AdoptTargetWidget()
{
   if ((_targetWidget)&&(_targetWidget->parentWidget() != this))
   {
      QLayout * layout = _targetWidget->layout();
      if (layout) layout->removeWidget(_targetWidget);

      _targetWidget->setParent(this);
      _layout->addWidget(_targetWidget);
   }
}

static void SetWidgetBackgroundColor(QWidget * w, const QColor bc)
{
   QPalette p = w->palette();
   p.setColor(QPalette::Window, bc);
   w->setAutoFillBackground(true);
   w->setPalette(p);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QTabWidget * tabWidget = new QTabWidget;
   tabWidget->setWindowTitle("Proxy Widget test");

   QWidget * proxyMe = new QLabel("Shared Widget!");
   SetWidgetBackgroundColor(proxyMe, Qt::green);

   int counter = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
      QWidget * nextTab = new QWidget;
      QBoxLayout * tabLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom, nextTab);

      const int numAbove = rand()%3;
      for (int i=0; i<numAbove; i++) tabLayout->addWidget(new QLabel(QString("Unshared label #%1 above").arg(++counter)));

      tabLayout->addWidget(new TabProxyWidget(proxyMe));

      const int numBelow = rand()%3;
      for (int i=0; i<numBelow; i++) tabLayout->addWidget(new QLabel(QString("Unshared label #%1 below").arg(++counter)));

      tabWidget->addTab(nextTab, QString("Tab %1").arg(i+1));
   }

   tabWidget->show();
   return app.exec();
}
```