# Is it possible to constrain a Qt parent QWidget to always be the same size as its child QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout

I've written a simple "proxy widget" class in Qt; the idea is that this widget will hold a single child QWidget and represent that widget in the `QWidget` hierarchy.  (FWIW, the motivation for doing this is to make it easy to [move the child widget around the hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088291/is-there-a-way-to-place-a-widget-into-more-than-one-of-the-tabs-of-a-qtabwidget) without having to directly disturb the state of various other container-`QWidgets` to do so).

This seems to work fairly well; the only problem I've run into is that I want my `ProxyWidget` to always be laid-out the same way as its child-`QWidget` would be (if the child had been added to the widget hierarchy directly); but instead I find that the `ProxyWidget` is often sized larger than its child would be, leading to wasted space in the GUI.

Therefore, is there some way I can craft my `ProxyWidget` class so that Qt's layout managers to move/size it exactly the same as if its child widget was added directly?

As a minimal test/example, you can compile the following code and run it with or without the "proxy" command line argument -- my goal is that the visual results would be the same either way, and in particular that you would never see any red pixels in the window (since red pixels indicate areas where the `ProxyWidget` has been sized larger than the blue child widget it contains)

[image: screenshots of example program, with and without "proxy" keyword supplied]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStackedLayout>
#include <QWidget>

class ProxyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
   ProxyWidget(QWidget * childWidget)
      : _childWidget(childWidget)
      , _layout(new QStackedLayout(this))
   {
      _layout->addWidget(childWidget);
      setSizePolicy(childWidget->sizePolicy());
   }

   virtual QSize sizeHint() const {return _childWidget->sizeHint();}
   virtual QSize minimumSizeHint() const {return _childWidget->minimumSizeHint();}

private:
   QWidget * _childWidget;
   QStackedLayout * _layout;
};

static void SetWidgetBackgroundColor(QWidget * w, const QColor bc)
{
   QPalette p = w->palette();
   p.setColor(QPalette::Window, bc);
   w->setAutoFillBackground(true);
   w->setPalette(p);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QWidget * win = new QWidget;
   win->setWindowTitle("Proxy Widget test");

   QWidget * proxyMe = new QWidget;
   proxyMe->setFixedSize(100, 50);
   SetWidgetBackgroundColor(proxyMe, Qt::blue);

   QBoxLayout * winLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom, win);

   if ((argc >= 2)&&(strcmp(argv[1], "proxy") == 0))
   {
      ProxyWidget * proxyWidget = new ProxyWidget(proxyMe);
      SetWidgetBackgroundColor(proxyWidget, Qt::red);

      winLayout->addWidget(proxyWidget);
   }
   else winLayout->addWidget(proxyMe);

   win->show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: since reading is sequential, i don't think it's possible to get the size of the child before creating the parent in normal ways.
I think the only way is to control it via events. So when you call a resize event or with a paint event, which updates at the start and returns the size of the child. but that would be a "cheap trick", I don't know if you want to have something like that in your program.

Comment: I have a hard time believing you do, actually, want what you describe. In a layout, the size of a widget depends on the other widgets around it. How would you manage your blue rectangle in a `QTabWidget` when it is supposed to be the only widget in the first tab but appear along with 2 other widgets in the second tab? Do you have a more complete example (with 2 separate blue rectangle instance) to demonstrate your case?

Comment: @Atmo it's based on the idea that layout only matters when the widgets are visible, and only one tab-page is visible at any given time.  I put a `ProxyWidget` into each tab, and each `ProxyWidget` has a pointer to the target (i.e. blue-rectangle) widget.  In my real implementation, each `ProxyWidget` has some logic inside its `showEvent()` method that calls `setParent(this)` on the target widget to itself and adds the target widget to its layout.  That way the target widget jumps to the currently-visible tab as necessary.

Comment: @Atmo I posted a working example of the solved issue here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75101250/131930

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I understood you wanted to reparent your widget to make it appear in several tabs but I still think it may result in a widget that e.g. correctly fills and entire tab  and causes mayhem in others. What you are trying to do would be valid for managing a uniform level of zoom/scrolling for a widget while placing it in scroll areas of different tabs, so the scroll area all comply to the layout they are placed on but not for a property that affects widgets around. I am really interested in seeing a real case example where this would be justified, if you can share.

Comment: @Atmo my real code is closed-source so I can't share the code, but in my real-world case the widget W is a digital audio mixer's GUI control surface with several hundred individual controls inside it, and a number of different display settings that the user can change to modify its appearance/behavior.  (It's really the latter that is motivating me more than performance, since having to carefully propogate every appearance/behavior change across multiple "clone widgets" is a pain, code-wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` of `ProxyWidget` is different from its child widget and setting them fix things in your particular example :

```
ProxyWidget(QWidget * childWidget)
        : _childWidget(childWidget)
        , _layout(new QStackedLayout(this))
    {
        _layout->addWidget(childWidget);
        setSizePolicy(childWidget->sizePolicy());

        this->setMinimumSize(childWidget->minimumSize());
        this->setMaximumSize(childWidget->maximumSize());
    }
```

However i am not sure it's the best solution but it might gives you a hint to a better one.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks!  In my actual code I installed an event filter on the target object so the `ProxyWidget` can call `setMinimumSize()` and `setMaximumSize()` on itself to match the target object's min/max size, in response to a `Resize` event on the target.